# ASP.NET MVC Wizard kind of logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a wizard kind of issue to solve in my MVC application. I have no Javascript and i have 3 Views, one for each step.

The scenario is: I have a 3 step process. S1 posts to S2 and S2 posts to S3.
If i have a model validation error, the error is catched on the next view because the data was already posted there. My code looks like: return(View, modeldata) if ok ELSE return ("PreviousView", modeldata). The problem is my URL that remains in the post url requested

Answer (score 3):

In all cases I would post each form back to the original controller / action and then forward to the appropriate next step... i.e.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StepOneNameHere() {
    StepOneModel model = new StepOneModel();

    // Populate any bits on the model...
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StepOneNameHere(StepOneModel model) {
    // Validation

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // You can add logic to choose the next step, for example if they have
        // selected an option that requires an additional step in the wizard or
        // if you can skip a step in the wizard
        return RedirectToAction("StepTwoNameHere");
    } else {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - sohnee - it might also be useful to send the name of the next step as a paramater as well. i.e. `public ActionResult StepOneNameHere(StepOneModel model, string nextStepActionName){}`

Comment: @Jim - that is a valid suggestion - it depends on what part of the framework you want to be in control of the decision. I would never dream of letting my view make that decision, so I would look at the model and judge what step needs to be performed next - probably not directly in the action method, but in a wizard helper.

Comment: Hi Sohnee, your suggestion requires me to do a redirect witch i was trying to avoid. Is that a good practice? Even so, i cannot pass the model to the action, i have to put it on session. Am i wrong?

Comment: yes it's good to use a session and do what sohnee did. redirect is good practice. posting to an other url isnt. (it confuses people when the url changes but the form with a bad validation returns)

Comment: That brings me another problem, i have to declare HttpGet ActionResults for actions that i dont want users to call directly (in URL)